# Archive all files of a certain type recursively from powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, archive, compress-archive

Is there a way to use Compress-Archive script, that when run from a path:

1. archives all files matching a wildcard filter (*.doc, for example)
2. archives such files in the current folder and all children folders
3. save the relative folder structure (the option to use relative or absolute would be good, though)

I am having trouble have it accomplish all three of these at once.

Edit:

The following filters and recurses, but does not maintain folder structure

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ".\" -Filter "*.docx" -Recurse |
Compress-Archive -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath "$pwd\doc.archive-$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd.hhmmss).zip"
```

This item does not recurse:

```
Compress-Archive -Path "$pwd\*.docx" -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath "$pwd\doc.archive-$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd.hhmmss).zip"
```

At some point I had a command that would recurse but not filter, but can't get back to it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, **`Compress-Archive` is quite limited** as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.1.0:

- The only way to preserve a subdirectory tree is pass a *directory path* to `Compress-Archive`.

  - Unfortunately, doing so provides *no inclusion/exclusion* mechanism to only select a subset of files.
  - Additionally, the resulting archive will internally contain a s*ingle root directory named for the input directory* (e.g., if you pass `C:\temp\foo` to `Compress-Archive`, the resulting archive will contain a single `foo` directory containing the input directory's subtree - as opposed to containing `C:\temp\foo`'s *content* at the top level).
  - There is no option to preserve *absolute* paths.
- A cumbersome work around is to *create a temporary copy of your directory tree* with *only the files of interest*  (`Copy-Item -Recurse -Filter *.docx . $env:TEMP\tmpDir; Compress-Archive $env:TEMP\tmpDir out.zip` - note that *empty* dirs. will be included)

  - Given that you'll still invariably end up with a single root directory named for the input directory inside the archive, even that may not work for you - see the alternatives at the bottom.

---

You may be better off with **alternatives**:

- Use the .NET v4.5+ [`[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile) and [`[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions) types directly.
  In Windows PowerShell, unlike in PowerShell *Core* (v6+), you most load the relevant assembly manually with `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` - see below.
- Use an external programs such as [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/)

---

#### Solving the problem with direct use of the .NET v4.5+ [`[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile) class:

Note:

- In Windows PowerShell, unlike in PowerShell *Core*, you most load the relevant assembly manually with `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`.
- Because PowerShell doesn't support *implicit* use of extension methods as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.1.0, you must make explicit use of the [`[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions) class as well.

```
# Windows PowerShell: must load assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem manually.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

# Create the target archive via .NET to provide more control over how files
# are added.
# Make sure that the target file doesn't already exist.
$archive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open(
  "$pwd\doc.archive-$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd.hhmmss).zip",
  'Create'
)

# Get the list of files to archive with their relative paths and
# add them to the target archive one by one.
$useAbsolutePaths = $False # Set this to true to use absolute paths instead.
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.docx | ForEach-Object {
    # Determine the entry path, i.e., the archive-internal path.
    $entryPath = (
          ($_.FullName -replace ([regex]::Escape($PWD.ProviderPath) + '[/\\]'), ''), 
          $_.FullName
        )[$useAbsolutePaths]
    $null = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile(
      $archive, 
      $_.FullName, 
      $entryPath
    )
  }

# Close the archive.
$archive.Dispose()
```